# Prove that $\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}<\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\alpha}<\frac{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Prove that if $\alpha>0$, then $$\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}<\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\alpha}<\frac{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}$$

I know that the Left and Right inequalities are the results of integration in this form:

$$\int n^\alpha dn<\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha<\int (n+1)^\alpha dn$$

Furthermore the right inequality can be given as a binomial expansion where $(n+1)^\alpha = \sum_{\alpha=0}^n \binom{n}{\alpha} n^\alpha$

We can obviously see by plugging $1$ into the inequality for $n,k$ we get:

$$\int 1^\alpha dn<\sum_{1}^n 1^\alpha<\int 2^{\alpha}\ dn$$

That the right inequality is the upper bound for this however, I'm unsure of the two equations left. For example after integration and taking the sum:

$$\int1^{\alpha}dn = n<\sum_1^n1^\alpha = n^\alpha\implies n<n^\alpha<2^\alpha n$$

Is this the correct approach?

Comment: $\int n^\alpha dn<\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha<\int (n+1)^\alpha dn$ does not make much sense because you have indefinite integrals on both sides. –  It should become much easier (almost obvious I would say) if you use the proper bounds for the integrals in the first step: $\int_0^n x^\alpha dx<\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha<\int_0^n (x+1)^\alpha dx$

Comment: @MartinR thanks for the tip although I'm unsure of how to proceed with this hint.

Comment: Do you agree that $\int_0^n x^\alpha dx<\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha<\int_0^n (x+1)^\alpha dx$? Can you compute the integrals $\int_0^n x^\alpha dx$ and $\int_0^n (x+1)^\alpha dx$? – Note that $x^\alpha$ has the anti-derivative $x^{\alpha+1}/(\alpha+1)$.

Comment: @MartinR Ah I see! I was suspecting a different way of proof rather than accepting the inequalities in their current position but much rather a re-arrangement to prove their positions. Though this is probably why I experience confusion. I was trying to show that $\int_o^n (x+1)^{\alpha}dn > \int_0^n \frac{(x+1)^\alpha}{(x+1)^\alpha}-\frac{\alpha x}{(x+1)^{\alpha}}$ to see whether it takes me anywhere

Comment: Is it clear now? Or do you still need an answer?

Comment: @MartinR I believe an answer with some detail will help make the result clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int n^\alpha dn<\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha<\int (n+1)^\alpha dn$ does not make much sense because you have indefinite integrals on both sides. Use definite integrals instead to estimate the sum:

For $1 \le k \le n$ and $k-1 \le x \le k$ is $x^\alpha \le k^\alpha \le (x+1)^\alpha$, with strict inequality except at one point. It follows that
$$
 \int_{k-1}^k x^\alpha \, dx < k^\alpha < \int_{k-1}^k (x+1)^\alpha \, dx
$$
for $k=1, \ldots, n$, and therefore
$$
\int_0^n x^\alpha dx<\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha<\int_0^n (x+1)^\alpha dx \, .
$$
Both integrals can be evaluated using the anti-derivative $x^{\alpha+1}/(\alpha+1)$. This gives
$$
\frac{n^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}<\sum_{k=1}^nk^{\alpha}<\frac{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}-1}{\alpha+1} < \frac{(n+1)^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}
$$

Comment: Then we can also show $-1<\alpha <0$ will reverse the integrals on each side given that $(x+1)^\alpha \le k^{\alpha} \le x^{\alpha}$. Although, could you help clarify with me why you chose these inequalities $1 \le k \le n$ and $k-1 \le x \le k$ I cannot seem to see it

Comment: @Stackbeans: $1 \le k \le n$ because we want to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n k^\alpha$. And $k-1 \le x \le k$ because the integral $\int_0^n$ is split into a sum of $n$ integrals over the intervals $[k-1, k]$.